# Vagrant + Oracle VM + Java Hybris debug

Tags: java, debugging, vagrant, virtualbox, sap-commerce-cloud

wrapper-debug.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.34=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.35=-Xnoagent
wrapper.java.additional.36=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
wrapper.java.additional.37=-Ddeployed.server.type=tomcat
```

Vagrantfile

```
 config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.11"
 config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

Idea remote connection host

```
192.168.56.11
```

Idea remote connection string

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

Hybris start

```
 sh hybrisserver.sh debug
```

And it is unable to connect in debug mode.
Why? What will fix this?

Comment: did you try access to port via telnet or equivalent tool? May be server has firewall and blocking port.

Comment: yes, it looks like unaccessible

Comment: Are you sure hybris running in debug mode? Can you see jvm debug mode message on hybris start? If you can see, check your server/client firewall rules.

Comment: @mkysoft i see only INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/02 22:41:50.534 | INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9001"]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/02 22:41:50.534 | Aug 02, 2018 10:41:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/02 22:41:50.534 | INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9002"]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/02 22:41:50.634 | Aug 02, 2018 10:41:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/08/02 22:41:50.634 | INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Comment: Arthur, try vargant provision, updatesystem and rebuild system

Comment: thx! @Sobik what means rebuild here? ant clean all?

Comment: @Arthur did u try `address=0.0.0.0:8000` instead of `address=8000` ??

Comment: @MohamedNabli, no, in 2023)))